# PAM: Authentication failure

Tags: authentication, aws, fish

Pardon for dumb question, just getting started with Linux, and I think this multiple questions all rolled into one.
I have setup a AWS Ubuntu machine.
I am getting to that machine from Windows by doing:

```
ssh -i "hyperledgerkeys.pem" ubuntu@ec2-18-205-150-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

that part works, I am logged in in my AWS machine as user `ubuntu` -- I believe its superuser.
I then followed instructions to install fish shell on my machine.  When I type `fish` I get the fish shell, and can see colors in my commands -- so that works.

As the last step, I would like to make fish my default shell, so I enter:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
```

It is at that point that I am being prompted for a password, and I believe that on AWS Ubuntu machines the password is `ubuntu`, however, that doesn't work.  I am getting:

```
chsh: PAM: Authentication Failure
```

So it looks like I don't know my own password, but I did not set up a password.  The SSH connectivity part is working off the private key I got from AWS.

Thank you

Comment: Does that user even have a password? Have you tried just using an empty password?

Answer (score 5):

You can set that user's password with `sudo`: `sudo passwd ubuntu` should do the trick. (Assuming you have access to sudo as I think fish needs root access to install.)

Comment: After setting the password, it worked.  Thank you

Comment: Would you mind marking this question as solved? thanks